# Dark spots appear when Subdivision modifier is added (even though normals are fine)

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I'm working on modelling a horse. However, when the subdivision modifier is added these dark spots appear, although all the normals are fine and the vertices are not protruding or sunken into the mesh.

I am an absolute beginner, so any advice is very welcome!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you say "normals are fine" face orientation when turned on the whole mash is all the same color? Also, try checking if there are any unattached mesh use face select and pull some faces see if anything tears apart.

Comment: Thank you for responding! Yes, when face orientation is turned on all faces are blue. When I select and pull away the faces, the mesh seems to deform normally.

Comment: Just to be safe, select the whole mesh in edit mode then press M (merge) and select _"By Distance"_ to make sure you don't have any duplicate or disconnected verts.

Comment: If none of those works, you can upload your file so we can take a look.

Comment: Thank you! Merge "By Distance" on the whole object fixed one of the dark spots :)

Comment: maybe you have inner faces, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: You can increase the merge distance using the operator panel that appears in the bottom left if needed (to maybe get more of the "spots"), but be careful you don't increase it too much and accidentally merge verts that are supposed to be apart. Often it's better to (very slowly) increment the distance by inputting numerical values as opposed to using the left and right arrows. For example, increase the last number by one at a time and keep an eye on the "deleted verts" count that appears in the bottom center in addition to how many dark spots are left on your mesh.

Comment: Increasing the "merge by distance" worked! THANK YOU EVERYONE!